# Use run by line with comments on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Aparently it is not possible to use run by line with any comments, as it should ignore the commented line and go to the next line but that's not what happens

Here is a run by line gif without comment
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPhLr.gif)

and here a cell with a comment using run by line, should this really happen or am I doing something wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTEH9.gif)

Using comments in the codes is good and I wish I could use it, but it's not the end of the world either hahaha

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the issue here but I believe you are trying to debug something. I would recommend the library which I used in notebooks called **pdb**
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to debug using jupyter's own tool, which worked before using comments, but i'll take a look at this library that you recommend, thanks